# Perl get array count so can start foreach loop at a certain array element

Tags: perl

I have a file that I am reading in. I'm using perl to reformat the date.  It is a comma seperated file.  In one of the files, I know that element.0 is a zipcode and element.1 is a counter.  Each row can have 1-n number of cities.  I need to know the number of elements from element.3 to the end of the line so that I can reformat them properly.  I was wanting to use a foreach loop starting at element.3 to format the other elements into a single string.

Any help would be appreciated.  Basically I am trying to read in a csv file and create a cpp file that can then be compiled on another platform as a plug-in for that platform.

Best Regards
Michael Gould

Comment: Missing parts of your question: What you have tried, sample input, actual and expected output.

Comment: What is `element.2`? Have you got out of step with your indices?

Comment: Surely the number of cities is the number of fields in the record minus 3?

Answer (score 2):

you can do something like this to get the fields from a line:

```
my @fields = split /,/, $line;
```

To access all elements from 3 to the end, do this:

```
foreach my $city (@fields[3..$#fields])
{
   #do stuff
}
```

(Note, based on your question I assume you are using zero-based indexing. Thus "element 3" is the 4th element).

Alternatively, consider [`Text::CSV`](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/Text-CSV-1.21/lib/Text/CSV.pm) to read your CSV file, especially if you have things like escaped delimiters.

Answer (score 1):

Well if your line is being read into an array, you can get the number of elements in the array by evaluating it in scalar context, for example

```
my $elems = @line;
```

or to be really sure

```
my $elems = scalar(@line);
```

Although in that case the `scalar` is redundant, it's handy for forcing scalar context where it would otherwise be list context. You can also find the index of the last element of the array with `$#line`.

After that, if you want to get everything from element 3 onwards you can use an array slice:

```
my @threeonwards = @line[3 .. $#line];
```